# Firebase segue authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently I'm working with a Firebase authentication and handled many errors like wrong username, password, empty fields etc and everything is working fine. However when I try to add a segue to the next page and use random email which is not exist in the database, Firebase auth didn't give me any errors and just pass the user to the next page. When I remove the segue and put random user it gives me an error that could not find such user which is what I'm trying to achieve with the segue. Please advise, what might be the problem?

**AuthService file**

```
func login(email: String, password: String, onComplete: Completion?) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.handleFirebaseError(error: error! as NSError, onComplete: onComplete)
        } else {
            onComplete?(nil, user)
        }

    })
}

func handleFirebaseError(error: NSError, onComplete: Completion?) {
    print(error.debugDescription)
    if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch (errorCode) {
        case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
            onComplete?("Invalid email address", nil)
            break
        case .errorCodeWrongPassword:
            onComplete?("Invalid password", nil)
            break
        case .errorCodeUserNotFound:
            onComplete?("Can't find user", nil)
            break
        default:
            onComplete?("There was a problem authentication. Try again", nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let pass = passwordField.text , (email.characters.count > 0 && pass.characters.count > 0)  {
        AuthService.instance.login(email: email, password: pass, onComplete: { (errMsg, data) in
            guard errMsg == nil else {
                self.alert(title: "Error Authentication", errMsg: errMsg!)
                return
            }
        })
    } else {
        self.alert(title: "Username and password required", errMsg: "You must enter both a username and a password")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hybridcattt is correct. I'm going to add a more specific answer. When using segues, make sure it the next screen is not directly connected from the button, otherwise it will fire as soon as you tap it, regardless of the result you're waiting for.

Connect your view controller instead to the next view controller, like so:

[image]

And then add an **indentifier** to that segue.

Finally, when you get what you're waiting for (e.g. successful logging in), then do the **performSegue**.

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed your instruction and the issue is resolved!

Comment: You're very much welcome. You might want to choose this as the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a segue in a storyboard, it fires immediately and opens the next view controller. Login code you have is async, and storyboard doesn't wait for it.

It is very likely that loginBtnTapped method is not even called if you have a segue configured (try adding a breakpoint there)